# How to handle duplicate db events with embedded debezium and spring boot service in case of multiple instances

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, debezium

I am using embedded debezium in my spring boot service to process db events that happens on my mongodb database.

I am using embedded-debezium and debezium-api and debezium-mongodb-connector dependencies in my service.

while everything is working fine and I am receiving db events whenever some change in any document happens in any collection, I have issue with multi instance deployment. If i deploy 3 instances of my service I recieve same event in  all 3 service instances which is issue for me. I only need to process that event only once.

So what would be a good approach to tackle this issue?

Comment: That is probably the default behavior that all 3 pick up change events. Can you have a Active/Standby set up ? May be use a simple election and have one active instance that processes data and use the others as standby

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing it out there, you can maintain a record of LSN and check if the received log has a LSN that was received before.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can appoint a specific profile to only one of the instances. With this profile, you can enable the configuration of the Debezium beans with the `@Profile("cdc")` annotation. This should result in Debezium being used in only one of the application instances. However, if this instance crashes, you need to ensure that a new one will spin up with the 'cdc' profile.

Another solution is to use distributed locks. These locks allow coordination within a set of instances of the same application. One way to utilise locking is by activating a lock before a message is processed, preventing other instances from doing so. And finally after handling the event, you can release the lock.

```java
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "debeziumOutputChannel")
public void processDebeziumEvent(Message<ChangeEvent<String, String>> message) {
    Lock lock = lockRegistry.obtain("my-lock-key");
    if (lock.tryLock()) {
        try {
            // Process the Debezium event
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    } else {
        // Another instance is already processing the event
    }
}
```

Locking can also be achieved on a higher level. It is possible for an instance to attempt to lock the CDC-process on startup. One thing to keep in mind is that when the instance shuts down or crashes, it should release the lock. The same can be done on the bean level with [Spring lifecycle events](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/factory-nature.html).

By the way, Spring [offers support for Debezium via Spring Integration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/debezium.html).